# How to Vertically Align the Mini-Frames in the Headline

Tags: beamer, vertical-alignment, mini-frames

I would like to -- Option 1: vertically align (vertically centered) both the frame title and the mini-frames (mini-circles) -- Option 2: decrease the height of the box containing the mini-frames. If you could help me for both options so I could improve my knowledge of LaTeX and Beamer, thanks[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJX1u.png)

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usetheme{Alan_test}
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{\vspace*{0cm}}{\vspace*{-3mm}}
\let\Tiny\tiny
\newcommand\Wider[2][3em]{%
\makebox[\linewidth][c]{%
  \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth+#1\relax}
  \raggedright#2
  \end{minipage}%
  }%
}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle} 
{
    \nointerlineskip
\begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=0.3cm,ht=2em,wd=\paperwidth]{frametitle}
    \vbox{}\vskip-2.5ex%
    \strut\insertframetitle\strut
    \end{beamercolorbox} 
}

\begin{document} 

\section{Part I}
\begin{frame} {Frame 1} 
     \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Part II}
\begin{frame}{Frame 2}
    Text
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found how to solve the question:
Just add the following code before the \begin{document} statement and adjust
the height using the \vskip command (4th line).

```
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{
  \vskip-0.8ex
  \begin{beamercolorbox}{section in head/foot}
  \vskip2pt\insertnavigation{\paperwidth}\vskip2pt
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
}
\makeatother
```